# Mongo index on embedded array and query using $lt and $gt

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have a collection with documents that look like this:

```
{'data': [{'Depth': 0.0, 'Value': 123.0},
          {'Depth': 0.5, 'Value': 456.0},
          {'Depth': 1.0, 'Value': 111.0},
          {'Depth': 1.5, 'Value': 321.0},
          {'Depth': 2.0, 'Value': 987.0},
          {'Depth': 2.5, 'Value': 666.0},
          ...
          {'Depth': 3.0, 'Value': 453.0}],
 'datatype': 'Sometype'
```

}

I want to execute queries that look like this:

```
curves = db.curvedata.findOne(
 {
  "datatype" : "Sometype",
  "data": {
   "$elemMatch": {
    "Depth" : { "$gt": 13000, "$lt": 13100 },
    "Value" : { "$gt": 20, "$lt": 100 } }}})
```

That is to find all curves within a Depth range and a Value range.

The question is - can I index all the data values so the above query is super-fast? And if so, will the `$lt` and `$gt` operators use the index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A query will only use 1 index.
However, you can make a multikey index:

`.ensureIndex({Depth:1,Value:1})`

Then, use `.explain()` to make sure the query is using the index you just made.

Answer (score 2):

Create one index

```
.ensureIndex({'data.Depth':1,'data.Value':1})
```

Answer (score 1):

You sure can! What you're looking for is a multikey index. You would create it by doing something like

```
db.curvedata.ensureIndex({"data.depth": 1})
```

Then you can query in the same way. You can run .explain() on both queries to find how much time you're saving, pre and post indexing.